# Tooltip skidding in NVD3 line chart

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

My linechart is perfect, but sometimes after 4 5 sec automatically my chart skids and then tooltip looks as in below photo(like it remains at previous position).
[image]

Not getting why it is happening.Kindly help.
Thanks in advance.

Technology : 
Java,
Angular JS,
NVD3 Charts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, you need to put below code in chart options,

```
clipVoronoi: false
```